# Minimize execution time of an VBA-Access function

Tags: sql, arrays, database, vba, ms-access

I am running the following function on a AutoExec macro in Access.

The issue is that it takes approximately 40 sec (!!!) to run it which is way too long for roughly 200 records.

Can anyone suggest any way to minimize this runtime ?

The GOAL of this code is basically to check for each record in the [RefreshedDatas table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rj5y.png) if one of the values in the multiple values' PartNo field exists in 2 possible fields from other [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu5kj.png) (see structure in picture : I have to check if either SparPartNo field either SerialPartNo field contain the value). If it is, I would write YES in a [WPRC Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rj5y.png) field, otherwise NO.

So as an example,

I checked and realized that the part 5) of the code is the one taking 39 secs while the first 4 parts take about 1 sec.

```
Function PopulationOfWPRCField()

'1) Create an access to the PartNo field (=Recordset) and store all its values in an array called arrayPartNo
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim connStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim PartNoSQL As String
    Dim arrayPartNo() As Variant

    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & "PathtoMyAccessDatabase\" & "NewVersion.accdb" & ";"
    conn.ConnectionString = connStr
    conn.Open
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    PartNoSQL = "SELECT PartNo FROM RefreshedDatas" '"SELECT PartNo FROM 12Dec"
    rs.Open PartNoSQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        arrayPartNo = rs.GetRows
    End If
    'Set rs = Nothing


'2) Same with fields SerialPartNo and SparePartNo from the WPRC_List (+ShipmentID for the 4th part of this code)
    Dim arraySerialPartNo() As Variant
    Dim arraySparePartNo() As Variant
    Dim arrayShipmentID() As Variant
    Dim SerialPartNoSQL As String
    Dim SparePartNoSQL As String
    Dim ShipmentIDSQL As String

    'For SpartNo

        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        SparePartNoSQL = "SELECT SparePartNo FROM WPRC_Parts_List"
        rs.Open SparePartNoSQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            arraySparePartNo = rs.GetRows
        End If
        'For i = 0 To UBound(arraySparePartNo, 2)
        '    Debug.Print arraySparePartNo(0, i)
        'Next i
        Set rs = Nothing

    'For SerialNo

        Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        SerialPartNoSQL = "SELECT SerialPartNo FROM WPRC_Parts_List"
        rs.Open SerialPartNoSQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            arraySerialPartNo = rs.GetRows
        End If
        'For i = 0 To UBound(arraySerialPartNo, 2)
         '   Debug.Print arraySerialPartNo(0, i)
        'Next i
        Set rs = Nothing

    'For ShipmentID

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
        ShipmentIDSQL = "SELECT [Shipment ID] FROM RefreshedDatas"  
        rs.Open ShipmentIDSQL, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
        If Not rs.EOF Then
            arrayShipmentID = rs.GetRows
        End If
        'For i = 0 To UBound(arrayShipmentID, 2)
         '   Debug.Print arrayShipmentID(0, i)
        'Next i
        Set rs = Nothing

        Set conn = Nothing

'3) We calculate the size of the GoodArray() we'll declare later on so that we can declare it properly
    Dim h As Integer
    Dim longest As Integer
    longest = 0
    For h = 0 To UBound(arrayPartNo, 2) ' in this loop we search for the longest character in arrayPartNo and store its size in "longest"
        If Len(arrayPartNo(0, h)) > longest Then longest = Len(arrayPartNo(0, h))
    Next h
    'MsgBox longest '63 in this case
    h = (longest + 1) / 8 ' since h was only used in the loop above we reuse it to store this = 8 -> size of the 2nd dimension of GoodArray() , it represents the biggest number of PartNo a cell in arrayPartNo contains
    longest = UBound(arrayPartNo, 2) ' same here, we just reuse the variable to store this -> size of the 1st dimension of GoodArray () , it represents the number of cells(=records) in arrayPartNo ( in the MainForm)



'4) Declaration of the 2-dimensional array GoodArray() and population of it
    Dim NumberOfPartNo As Integer ' Number of PartNo in a specific row
    Dim length As Integer ' length of a correct PartNo
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim GoodArray() As Variant ' this is a 2 dimensional array where 1st dimension contains UBound(arrayPartNo, 2) cells and 2nd dimension contains the number of PartNo (=NumberOfPartNo) for the row determined by the 1st dimension)
    ' reason for (longest+1)/8 : we have the following equation : x*7 + (x-1)= longest where x is the number of PartNo( but for the record which has the most PartNo) and (x-1) is the number of ";" separating all those PartNo, the total gives the number of character of the record (= longest for the record with the most PartNo)
   ReDim Preserve GoodArray(longest, h)
For i = 0 To UBound(arrayPartNo, 2)

    length = 7
    NumberOfPartNo = 0
    If Len(arrayPartNo(0, i)) > 0 Then
            Do
                GoodArray(i, NumberOfPartNo) = Mid(arrayPartNo(0, i), length + 1 - 7, 7)
                NumberOfPartNo = NumberOfPartNo + 1
                length = length + 8

            Loop While Len(arrayPartNo(0, i)) >= length ' since we use such a loop it allows any PartNo to go through it even if it has less than 6 characters
        End If
Next i

'5) Comparison of the arrays : For each element contained in GoodArray() check if it is included in arraySerialPartNo or arraySparePartNo
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
'Dim OnList As Boolean
For i = 0 To UBound(GoodArray, 1)
    k = 0
    'OnList = False
    Do Until GoodArray(i, k) = ""
        For j = 0 To UBound(arraySerialPartNo, 2)
            If arraySerialPartNo(0, j) = GoodArray(i, k) Then
                DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE RefreshedDatas Set [WPRC Part] = 'Yes' WHERE [Shipment ID] = " & arrayShipmentID(0, i)
                'OnList = True
                GoTo Prochain
            End If
        Next j

        For j = 0 To UBound(arraySparePartNo, 2)
            If arraySparePartNo(0, j) = GoodArray(i, k) Then
                DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE RefreshedDatas Set [WPRC Part] = 'Yes' WHERE [Shipment ID] = " & arrayShipmentID(0, i)                   
                'OnList = True
                GoTo Prochain
            End If
        Next j

        k = k + 1
    Loop

    DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE RefreshedDatas Set [WPRC Part] = 'No' WHERE [Shipment ID] = " & arrayShipmentID(0, i)        
Prochain:

Next i

End Function
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling? You know, it is your code, so **you** oughta know what it is doing; and where it is spending its time. You see, this is not a free "we debug your performance problems for you" service.

Comment: I suggest you go over the logic of what you want to achieve and rewrite it. It seems to pull in too much data and does many lookups/compares, some of which could be done by the database.

Comment: This looks like recordset overkill. I would have thought you could easily pull in most of this data using simple table joins, no recordset / array processing required.

Comment: @GhostCat : I don't know what profiling is. Never tried it but I will check what that is. I tried different ways to achieve the result I want but this one seemed to be the best except on a runtime point of view.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie : The GOAL of this code is basically to check for each records, if the Part No is on one of the 2 special PartNo lists' from an other table. If it is, I would write YES in a certain field, otherwise NO

Comment: @Minty : Ok. Could you suggest me a way to start this please ? I tried to use a 1/dimensional array only at some point but thought it was easier to use this 2 dimensional one (GoodArray) eventually

Comment: Why on the earth are you using Arrays when dealing with Databases? i.e. Why would you read a db into an array and sort it if DB can sort it for you? I would say start learning SQL.

Comment: @krishKM : What are your suggestions in order to achieve the same result ? (see edit)

Comment: In Access queries, it is possible to use most VBA functions in SQL, to compare and to compute things. You might be able to reform that entire macro into a single UPDATE query.

Comment: Without seeing your data structure it's very difficult to comment. However initially can you simply query your tables to get your desired records returned. if you can then you should be able to join those results to give you the basis for your update.

Comment: @Minty: Ok I will then make a query which take those 2 fields and add the records of one to then end of the other and then simply go through each records of that new "full field"

Comment: possibly the best way is to post some sample data and the desired output!

Comment: @krishKM : I editted the post adding pictures of the 2 tables in question + the related fields . Also tried to explain the goal in a better way

Comment: all three pictures are same?

Comment: @krishKM: My bad, sorry about that. There are 2 different pictures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The GOAL of this code is basically to check for each record in the
>   RefreshedDatas table if one of the values in the multiple values'
>   PartNo field exists in 2 possible fields from other table (see
>   structure in picture : I have to check if either SparPartNo field
>   either SerialPartNo field contain the value). If it is, I would write
>   YES in a WPRC Part field, otherwise NO.

As far as I can understand, you need this..

```
UPDATE  RefreshedDatas
SET WPRC = "NO"; // Everything is set to no.
```

now test this sql, which will list all parts and if any parts found in the partno collection. PartNo.Value is the way to access items in a multiple value field.

```
Select
R.SparePartNo
R.SerialPartNo
iif(isnull(R2.PartNo.value),"No", "Yes") as [Part found]
FROM RefreshedDatas as R left join RefreshedDatas as R2
    ON (R.SparePArtNo = R2.PartNo.Value OR R.SerialPartNo = R2.PArtNo.Value);
```

Backup your tables and try this update. Similar to join the tables, you can also use a sub query to select and find the values from another table or same table.

```
UPDATE RefreshedDatas
SET WPRC = "YES"
WHERE 
//if SparePartNo is available in the PartNo collection
    RefreshedDatas.SparePartNo in (SELECT P.PartNo.Value from RefreshedDatas as P WHERE P.ID = RefreshedDatas.ID)
// or if the SerialPartNo is available in the partNo Collection.
OR RefreshedDatas.SerialPartNo (SELECT S.PartNo.Value from RefreshedDatas as S WHERE S.ID = RefreshedDatas.ID)
```

have no means to test the code but you should get some idea how this works in SQL.
Remove the "P WHERE P.ID = RefreshedDatas.ID" if you want to search for a part number in entire PartNo collection and not in the same row

Comment: Big thanks for this ! I will try to implent those ideas and le you know if I manage to make it work

Comment: I tried to implement it in my code but seems like the ".value" part doesn't work. Are you sure about this way to retrieve datas from a multiple values record ? I checked online and didn't find any information about SQL on multiple values records

Answer (score 2):

No really a reply, but...

**IF** your 2 tables have proper Primary keys, **and**
**IF** you define a proper relationship (with referential integrity) between the 2 tables

**THEN** you won't even have to check if there is a match, and you can just delete that code.

And anyway that code could be done with just update queries, if I understood it well. I don't see a reason to play with arrays.

I would even think that you dont need an update query. Just use a `SELECT` query with a `LEFT JOIN` including a formula indicating "Match" or "No match"

Comment: I thought about doing it, but it is ( I think) a bit more complex since I have to check in not 1 but 2 fields from the 2nd table to see if the PartNo value in question exists.