# SQL Access on records that "Allow multiple value"

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

Are there any articles or other form of information regarding ways to retrieve/ compare datas from fields with records that can contain multiple values ?

[image]

As suggested on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42065010/minimize-execution-time-of-an-vba-access-function/42068210#42068210) I am trying to replace my way-to-long code by an SQL statement but I can't manage to make it run :

```
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "UPDATE 12Dec " _
& "Set [WPRC Part] = 'YES' " _
& "WHERE " _
& "12Dec.PartNo.value in (SELECT SparePartNo FROM WPRC_Parts_List) " _
& "OR 12Dec.PartNo.value in (SELECT SerialPartNo FROM WPRC_Parts_List) "
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
```

In the above code:

- *12Dec* is a table that contains the fields WPRC Part and PartNo (field that allows multiple values in its records)
- *WPRC_Parts_List* is a table that contains the fields SpartPartNo and SerialPartNo

Comment: What is the error? Can you write `Debug.print SQL` before the last line and see what you are getting? Then simply copy and paste the sql to the SQL in Access and see what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your code produces this SQL:

`UPDATE 12Dec Set [WPRC Part] = 'YES' WHERE 12Dec.PartNo.value in (SELECT SparePartNo FROM WPRC_Parts_List) OR 12Dec.PartNo.value in (SELECT SerialPartNo FROM WPRC_Parts_List)`

Are you sure that `12Dec.PartNo.value` is column name? Take a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_in

Comment: yes, I mean the name of the multivalued field is _PartNo_ Then the error I get is Run-time error 3075 : Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 12Dec.PartNo.value in ....WPRC_Parts_List)

Comment: Thanks for your link though because it allowed me to find the error. Basically I just removed the 12Dec in the WHERE section and it runs correctly. The weird thing is that I am sure I tried it before and it didn't work...So `UPDATE 12Dec Set [WPRC Part] = 'YES' WHERE PartNo.value in (SELECT SparePartNo FROM WPRC_Parts_List) OR PartNo.value in (SELECT SerialPartNo FROM WPRC_Parts_List)`

Comment: Basically when I wrote take a look at  `12Dec.PartNo.value` I have thought that `.value` is the wrong part... But still, happy that helped. :)